# How do I implement subclassable singletons?

Tags: python

Here I'm subclassing a wxPython class and defining a class method called `singleton`.

```
class AddressCellAttr(wx.grid.GridCellAttr):
    _instance = None

    def __init__(self):
        wx.grid.GridCellAttr.__init__(self)

        self.SetTextColour('#0000FF')

    @classmethod
    def singleton(cls):
        if cls._instance == None:
            cls._instance = cls()

        return cls._instance

class ValidAddressCellAttr(AddressCellAttr):
    def __init__(self):
        AddressCellAttr.__init__(self)

        self.SetTextColour('#00FF00')

class CorrectedAddressCellAttr(AddressCellAttr):
    def __init__(self):
        AddressCellAttr.__init__(self)

        self.SetTextColour('#FFFF00')

class InvalidAddressCellAttr(AddressCellAttr):
    def __init__(self):
        AddressCellAttr.__init__(self)

        self.SetTextColour('#FF0000')

class UnparsableAddressCellAttr(AddressCellAttr):
    def __init__(self):
        AddressCellAttr.__init__(self)

        self.SetTextColour('#555555')
```

The rest of the classes are subclasses of the first subclass. I figured that the singleton class method would work for all the subclasses as well since it operates on the class, and the subclass is indeed a separate class.

What happens is that after I call `singleton` once on `AddressCellAttr`, the singleton method returns that same object on all the subclasses too. Why does this happen?

Comment: -1 for blatant and gratuitous abuse of singletons, and for trying to get us to help you inflict this monstrosity upon the world.

Comment: @cHao: Please read the latest comment I wrote on sr2222's answer and, unless you can explain to me a better way to solve my problem than using singletons, remove the negative vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you think you  need a singleton pattern here, but in any case, you should really be doing this in `__new__`.

```
class Singleton(object):

    def __new__(cls):

        try:
            return cls._instance
        except AttributeError:
            cls._instance = object.__new__(cls)
            return cls._instance
```

Just make sure all subclasses call parent `__new__()`, and remember that the signature for `__new__()` and `__init__()` must match.

Comment: I'm using a singleton pattern because none of these classes needs to be instantiated more than once. Why else would somebody use a singleton pattern?

Comment: @Codemonkey: The only valid reason for using the singleton pattern is if the class *can't* be instantiated more than once (for instance, if creating another instance will open a wormhole or set the machine on fire).  If you just don't *want* but one instance, there's a much simpler fix -- **don't *create* but one.**  You make everything a singleton, and now you're adding code to enforce constraints that should not even exist...not to mention, hard-coding class-specific stuff all over the place, making future changes a nightmare.

Comment: @cHao: It's not as simple as it sounds. Defining the classes as singletons is probably much easier than maintaining single instances in my situation. The classes are used *a lot* in my code and it takes much more code for me to check the globals for instances every time I need to use them than it takes to just implement them as singletons. Additionally I can't just instantiate one of each class at the top of the module, because wxPython doesn't allow me to create `wx.grid.GridCellAttr` objects until after `wx.App.OnInit` (and that happens in a different module)

Comment: @Codemonkey: As for checking for instances every time...create them when you init, and you're done.  Or, create one for each cell.  These objects appear *intended* to be attached to a cell, so creating one for each cell makes more sense than having one slutty instance flitting around between all the cells.  And even a million of them are not going to kill the app.

Comment: Add to all that... *this thing can be cloned*.  Which defeats the whole freaking purpose of a singleton.

Comment: @cHao: Fine. I'm now creating a new instance for every cell, just to spare you the thought of this singleton abusing monstrosity running on my PC. The application probably consumes a few more kB of memory and takes a few ms longer for every command now. I hope you're happy.

Comment: @Codemonkey: A few µs, you mean.  If Python is very slow.  And it doesn't have to be that way anyway.  You just apparently stopped reading your design patterns book after Singleton, and never got around to Observer.  Is there really no "init done" or "ready to display" event for you to latch onto and set up some slutty instances?

Comment: @cHao: Sure there is, but that doesn't exactly sound any *simpler* than the 5 lines it took to make the class a singleton though - that's all I'm contesting.

Comment: @Codemonkey: Never mind the gotcha that prompted this very question.  And it's 5 lines + 1 for each class.  An event handler doesn't sound any simpler *right now*, but it'd would take like one line to create the handler, one to attach it, plus one line per thing you create.  Besides that, you also get the peace of mind that comes with knowing exactly when your objects will be created.

Comment: @Codemonkey: On top of that, what's the biggest reason for the five different classes?  The 4 child classes each need to be singletons, right?  With that requirement removed, now that you're able to create more than one instance of the class, you could have *one* class, with a constructor that takes the color for that kind of cell, and create 4 instances with the appropriate colors.  ~25 lines become 4-5.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I kind of figured this one out myself while writing the question. It turns out that when the singleton method is called it does indeed receive the correct subclass as the parameter, but since the subclasses don't specifically define `_instance` anywhere, `cls._instance` will look up the class chain back to `AddressCellAttr` and to the original `_instance`.

The solution is to specifically define `_instance` for each subclass, like so:

```
class ValidAddressCellAttr(AddressCellAttr):
    _instance = None

    def __init__(self):
        AddressCellAttr.__init__(self)

        self.SetTextColour('#00FF00')
```

And so on.